# Generating end-user friendly descriptions of unique_together relationships for fields in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

basically my problem can be summarized as below.
Problem domain is Real estate.

I have an ApartmentSpace table, where each row represents a rentable apartment_flat/ space with given set of facilities (such as all the utilities, amenities, floor size, number of and type of available rooms etc.) and I have a Property table, which may have one or more apartments added as ManyToMany Field. One single apartment_space_id may be attached to more than one property in this case (as many apartments in the real world may be represented with same set of facilities, I will assume all such apartments to have a single apartment_space_id only)

So, a single rentable unit will be represented by a pair of (apartment_space_id, property_id) representing a unique_together relationship for that rentable unit in physical world. Bonus: if possible I would also want to represent within that Property, all the apartments attached to that property as identifiable with a local_apartment_space_id, that will give an auto-incrementing id to all the attached apartments for that property only and not depend on global apartment_space_id primary key for Apartment table.

Now my problem is that if I want to send notification to the end-user for the rentable-unit, let's say for an apartment_space_id equal to 8, and property_id equal to 3, local_apartment_space_id equal to 4, I do not want it to look like this:
 **"Hi, you have a notification for (apartment_space_id=8, property_id=3) rentable-unit"**, but instead I want it to look like this:

**"Hi, you have a notification for your rented property: 4th studio-space on west-corridor at 9th floor of Hibiscus apartment complex"**. Any good way to achieve this? Notification description text will be generated in a string format inside my view function.

fairly simple model detail, although I don't think is really needed in this case but I will provide anyways, would look like this:

```
class ApartmentSpace(models.Model):
    apartment_space_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    apartment_facilities = models.ForeignKey(ApartmentFacilitiesObject, On_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Property(models.Model):
    property_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    property_name = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    apartments = models.ManyToManyField(ApartmentSpace)
```

Bonus: How do I generate local_apartment_space_id for each Property model instance?
I am also considering to connect Apartment and Property using a membership model with some kind of through_fields pairings using (apartment_space_id, apartment_name, floor_located, floor_location_descriptor, property_id), but I do not know much how to use membership for this case, so I appreciate your help.

Comment: An `AppartmentSpace` can belong to multiple `Property`s?

Comment: Yes, as it does not represent a physical apartment in real world, but a representation of all apartments that have same set of facilities

Comment: If other property also has a rentable-space that has same set of facilities, I will connect same apartment_space_id to both properties.